# Keep running bash command after closing terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I want to keep running following command even after I closes terminal.

```
while sleep 120; do cmd; done &
```

But currently it doesn't. Thanks. ps I am new to terminal

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it

Comment: You could use `nohup` (see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [How can I close a terminal without killing the command running in it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4004/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
while true ; do sleep 120; done 0<&- >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown ;
```

What it does :

- Launch the command in the background with `&`
- Send both stdout and sterr to `/dev/null` (you could redirect elsewhere)
- Close `stdin` with `0<&-`
- Remove the job from the shell's job list to protect it against being sent a signal when the shell terminates

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using tmux.

Install tmux if it isn't installed on your system.

1. Enter a tmux session `tmux`
2. Run you command: 
   `while [ 1 ]; do sleep 120; <your_commands_here>; done &`
3. Detach session: `tmux detach`
4. `exit`

More information can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Edit: Fred's solution is more adequate for this purpose

Comment: It might be appropriate to note here that `tmux` (or GNU `screen`) are utilities that allow to create interactive sessions which can be protected from a network disconnect (accidental or intended), and later re-connected to.  This is certainly immensely useful, but you would probably not want to use that as the way to run daemon-like processes.

Comment: How is that while loop wrong? It will run `cmd` every 120 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code, your while loop is just fine (editing answer). @fred I agree, your solution is more adequate.